# Why are the returned data the same?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```js
let statList = {
  title: {
    x: "center"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    axisTick: {
      alignWithLabel: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: "value"
  }
};

let statObj = {};

statObj.chatObj = Object.create(statList);
statObj.carObj = Object.create(statList);
statObj.saObj = Object.create(statList);

statObj.chatObj.xAxis.data = [1, 2, 3];
statObj.carObj.xAxis.data = [4, 5, 6];
statObj.saObj.xAxis.data = [7, 8, 9];

console.log(statObj)
```

Why are the returned `statObj.XX.xAxis.data` the same?

Why when I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(statObj))`, the result is `{"chatObj":{},"carObj":{},"saObj":{}}` ?

Comment: Try this:  alert( (statObj.chatObj === statList) );  That will tell you if a copy of statList has been created or infact it is just a reference to statList, which would explain why they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I do solve this by using the following trick

```
statObj.chatObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(statList));
```

I do not say this is a good practice, but in this way I am making sure the created object has it's own adress in the memory.

The problem with `Object.assign()` is that it is not working with nested properties, anyway the created object's are mutable.

Comment: This is what I have always done too. I only learned there were other ways because of stack overflow. And actually this question is my first time seeing 'Object.create' !

Answer (score 2):

While setting `statObj.chatObj.xAxis`, `xAxis` is not found on `chatObj`, so `xAxis` is searched on the prototype chain (`statList` is the prototype of `chatObj`), where we could find it there. Until now we are done with the part `statObj.chatObj.xAxis`, next we move to create a `.data` key which will be create on `statList.xAxis`. Assignments with both `statObj.carObj.xAxis.data` and `statObj.saObj.xAxis.data` oberride what was set by `statObj.chatObj.xAxis.data` on `statList.xAxis.data`, that is why we have the result of `statObj.XX.xAxis.data` the last set value which is `[7, 8, 9]`.